RPGMaker MZ paralax color depth
I've experimented a bit with tilesets and found out the hard way that they are hard limited in:
max. number: 5, the maximum pixels they can contain AND a fixed maximum colordepth of 24. This makes it very hard to combine multiple tilesets into one (due to other colors being used most of the time).
Now as alternative to them I've looked into paralax mapping. I found out that the typical max size should be around 80x80 tiles in total (and an appropriate number of pixels) due to RAM usage and that the color of each pixel is stored.
Now my question (to which I found no data) is: Is there also a maximum colordepth for paralax mapping like also 24 color depth max? Or does it work just like a normal png (and thus I can easily combine multiple tilesets on that map that way)?

Where are you finding a claim that RPG Maker MZ tilesets can only contain 24 colours? They can handle full 8 bits per channel RGB (24 bits = ~16 million colours), plus 8 bits of alpha — the same as a normal PNG.

@DMGregory I tried a few times to combine different tilesets into 1. But whenever I saved the files the editor at the part where you can select tiles  showed only black. I then noticed that the tilesets I saved had a color depth of 26 to 32 bit. When I dithered that down to 24 bits, the tiles were then shown normally in the editor (and as they had different base colors...lets say the result wasnt pretty after the dithering).  Thus I came to the conclusion. otherwise I'm not sure what went wrong there.

Try walking us through the exact steps you took to combine the tilesets, in what program, and what file type you saved as at the end. 26 bit isn't a thing, and 32 bit vs 24 bit only differs by alpha, so it does not affect the bits available for RGB colours.

@DMGregory I think that is best done then with screenshots. will do so in a separate question (I think that is easier that way). gimme about 30 mins to setit all up

hmmm you were right there. I dont get it why it didnt work before but then it must have been a saving error made by me somehow. thanks (just noticed it suddenly working when I tried to make screenshots)

It's generally better to edit a question rather than posting a new one.
